# Correct My preg_match function

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have some data I want to get the values from:

```
 Mobile:7899886788  bal:0.0    p=1898668
```

I have made a `preg_match` function for this:

```
preg_match('#Mobile:(.*?)  bal:0.0    p=(.*?)#',$html,$matches);
$a=matches[1];
$a1=$matches[2];
```

I am getting value for `$a` but value for `$a1` is not found. Please tell me what the issue is with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The second group in your regex will always match an empty string due to the fact that the `*?` quantifier is lazy.

If you always have digit values after `Mobile:` and `p=`, you may replace all your dot lazy matching patterns with a simple digit matching pattern `\d+`:

```
'#Mobile:(\d+)\s+bal:0\.0\s+p=(\d+)#'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aenuVO/2).

Note the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot. Also, it is a good idea to replace literal spaces with a `\s+` pattern that matches any 1 or more whitespace characters.

Another approach is to capture any 1+ non-whitespace symbols after the attributes you need with `\S+`:

```
'#Mobile:(\S+)\s+bal:\S+\s+p=(\S+)#'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aenuVO/3)